# Apostrophe rendered differently in html, notebook and Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

This is a problem I have been having for the longest time and have found no solution.

When a rmd file below is used to render html, notebook and pdf, the apostrophe is rendered differently.
In Rstudio it is also rendered differently.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: 
  html_document: default
  html_notebook: default
  pdf_document: default
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
```
````

I am using RStudio (Version 1.3.1093) on Windows 10 Pro
Language settings on English USA

How to fix such that the Rstudio and notebook renders the apostrophe correctly?

**HTML Document render**
[image: html_document render]

**Notebook document render**
[image: html_notebook render]

**PDF Document render**
[image: pdf_document render]

**RStudio Rmarkdown render**
[image: Rstudio rmarkdown render]

Comment: Given that your question is about apostrophes, it is a bit confusing to see `'` instead of backticks (`\``) in the code you provided. Is this just a typo?

Comment: '''{r}
library(tidyverse)
'''
should be 
```{r}
library(tidyverse)
```
As you can see the 3 back ticks does not show in the post